# monitor all running aws instances with grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, grafana, prometheus

Im trying to identify a way to list all running instances with grafana. Have any of you been able to do this?

Essentially I want a grafana dashboard to display:

Instance-ID >> Region >> Status(up or down) >> Current running time

Do any of you know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do that in grafana, but you can see just the information you want (except for the running time) in the prometheus alert module.

You can find it if you go to `prometheus:9090 -> Status -> Targets`

It should look something like [this](https://coreos.com/sites/default/files/inline-images/p2.png)

Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom, But that would require me to add a node exporter on each instance.

Ultimately I would like to either use the cloudwatch integration somehow, or use the cli to pull the data and inject it into promethius.

Comment: we just started using zabbix (generic alarms - like the one you described) along side prometheus, and maybe that would be more suitable for your use case...although that would also require you to install an agent on every node but it would give you an easy dashboard with all the info that you want....

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes to this thread, I have resolved my predicament by using the aws cli.

Essentially I broke it down into two pieces, first get the list of regions, then second get all the instance information i required:

```
echo Grabbing instances in all regions, please wait..
for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f3);
do
> $region.txt;
$quote="'";
aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`]| [0].Value,State.Name,InstanceType,PublicIpAddress,Placement.AvailabilityZone,LaunchTime]' --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --output json >> /home/ubuntu/$region.txt; done
```